# Cross Browser Support for Chart.js

Tags: firefox, html5-canvas, cross-browser, chart.js, microsoft-edge

I have inherited an application that uses Chart.js, it recently broke in the newest version of Firefox 69.0.3 giving [NS_ERROR_FAILURE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Errors) errors. [Firefox's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Errors) is not exactly helpful in pinpointing the cause of the error.

My hunch is that it has something to do with the way Chart.js is making use of `<canvas>`. Has anyone ever found a cross-browser solution for Chart.js? In Firefox, the canvas breaks and does not complete rendering the website. In Edge, the bars in the chart have an infinite height. No errors in Edge. The application works fine in Chrome. This application has only been tested in a Windows environment and I have not tested this application on Mac or Safari.

I tried upgrading to a different version of Chart.js, it still hasn't fixed the error.

[image: NS_ERROR_FAILURE]

Side note, I get an additional NS_ERROR_FAILURE error in regards to the retina display in Firefox only when using the application on my retina display screen. When I open it up on a normal screen, that particular error goes away but the rest of the errors remain.

Comment: I have created a [sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/gOOGWdB) with refer to the [Chart.js official sample code](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/) and use the Chart.js 2.8.0 version, the code works well on my machine (using Microsoft Edge 44..18362.1.0 version, Chrome, Firefox 70.0 (64-bit)version and IE browser). You could test it on your machine. If still not working, try to clear the browser data and reset the browser setting. Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after digging through many archived [github comments](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/423#issuecomment-269838075). Apparently, you cannot have the `canvas` set to a fixed height, set `responsive: true` and `maintainaspectratio: false`. When I altered any of these parameters, the bug went away.

Comment: Thankyou - solved my issue, would have taken me forever to find that one!

Comment: You're welcome! How about an up vote?